# Links/Urls are being treated as text in ckeditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

So I'm using ckeditor in my website chat and for some odd reason, if a user enters a link/url, it gets disabled and gets treated as a normal text.

At first it was treated as p tags, but then I tried to disable the auto p tag by using

```
config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
```

But that didn't solve the problem. The links are still treated as text. Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the [Auto Link](http://ckeditor.com/addon/autolink) plugin and require it in config.js

```
config.extraPlugins = 'autolink';
```

Comment: Thanks! I know there is one but it only takes http:// ... Let's say I want to enter www.google.com, this won't work.

Comment: you could change the var validUrlRegex at line 10 of autolink/plugin.js, but ckeditor doesn't autolink anything out of the box without an additional plugin

Comment: Yes I'm trying to that atm. To be honest, I'm not that good at Regex expressions. :P

Comment: Can check multiple url patterns with the same Regex Expr?